# AJAX countdown timer to show hours and not days

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer

I've implemented this AJAX countdown timer successfully:
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1085601.aspx

I created these 3 labels:

```
        Label1.Text = time1.Hours.ToString();
        Label2.Text = time1.Minutes.ToString();
        Label3.Text = time1.Seconds.ToString();
```

Lets say I set the timer countdown from over 24 hours (say 72 hours)

```
        Session["time"] = DateTime.Now.AddHours(72);
```

How can I make **Label1.Text** show **72** instead of 24 so that I have no need to add the Day label as follows?

```
        Label0.Text = time1.days.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate the hours from time:

`Label1.Text = ((time1.Days * 24) + time1.Hours).ToString()`

Comment: Thanks for that. I also found a jQuery version of that:
- http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html